# JPA Query by setting parameter to query object is returning empty list

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I am trying to query datastore using two approaches as below:

**Approach 1**:  Hardcode parameter value in querystring:

```
 String queryString="SELECT b FROM Item AS b WHERE b.categoryId=4";
 Query q = mgr.createQuery(queryString);
 List<Item> itemList = (List<Item>) q.getResultList();
```

**Approach 2**: set parameter to the query object:

```
 String queryString="SELECT b FROM Item AS b WHERE b.categoryId=:catId";
 Query q = mgr.createQuery(queryString);
 String parameterValue="4";
 q.setParameter("catId", parameterValue);
 List<Item> itemList = (List<Item>) q.getResultList();
```

While the first approach is returning results correctly, second approach always return an empty list.Why is it so?Is there some way I can check whether parameter is set correctly in query object?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the records based on categoryId use below method

```
public Item getItemByCategoryId(String categoryId) {
    Item item = null;
    try {
        item = mgr.find(Item.class, categoryId); // for single record
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return item;
}
```

or

Get all records based on categoryId

```
// for all the records which are mapped by categoryId
public List<Item> getItemListByCategoryId(String categoryId) {
    List<Item> itemsList = null;
    try {
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT b FROM Item AS b WHERE b.categoryId=:catId";
        Query query = mgr.createQuery(sqlQuery);
        query.setParameter("catId", categoryId);
        itemsList = query.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return itemsList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using a String for parameter if it's a number?

Try:

```
String queryString="SELECT b FROM Item AS b WHERE b.categoryId=:catId";
Query q = mgr.createQuery(queryString);
Integer parameterValue=4;
q.setParameter("catId", parameterValue);
List<Item> itemList = (List<Item>) q.getResultList();
```